# Python version recommendation

Tags: python

I have developed some internal tools at work using Python. I have been using version 2.5 (or 2.6/2.7) for that and my personal projects as they would work fine with Django and GAE. My question is - should I be switching to version 3 or shall I wait and continue to work with 2.5/2.6/2.7. How stable is 3.0 as compared to 2.x? And what is the switching curve? Thanks.

Comment: Python 3.x is very stable and the differences to 2.x are small.  The problem is that many third-party libraries have not yet been ported -- including [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3).

Comment: Searching stackoverflow for 'python 3' will bring up a number of related/duplicate questions. This first hit in particular may answer your question.

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading your code as far along the 2.x chain as possible. The later version of 2.x you can support, the easier it will be to move to 3 when the time comes. Note that there's a lot of 3.x features that got backported to 2.6 and 2.7, like the `//` operator and dict views.

Comment: see http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html, especially for print_function and unicode_literals. It will ease future porting to 3.x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python 3 isn't supported by Django and quite a few other notable projects. Although Python 3 (current version is 3.2.1 IIRC) is plenty stable, that's not the issues. The real issue is adoption and library support, and Python 3 does not have enough of either yet. I don't know of anyone using it in production.

The learning curve for switching is pretty small. You can pretty much learn everything you need from [What's New in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html), and most porting of code is pretty trivial.

I would not recommend that you switch anything that you use in production or professionally to Python 3. For your personal projects, it's okay to use Python 3 as long as the libraries you are using support it (for example, a Django project would not be able to use Python 3). Likewise for AppEngine; for that, you'll have to stick to Python 2.5.

So, in short, you can play around with Python 3, but it's not wise to use it at work because it likely does not support the libraries that you need, and it's not widely installed like Python 2.x is. I'd start thinking about Python 3 and familiarize yourself with it, but don't switch just yet.

You may also be interested in [Should I Choose Python 2 or 3](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

Comment: The last article should be enough! +1

Comment: Thanks Rafe. This helps me stay with 2.x right now. Will surely read the article.